# problam get element value from dynamic URL Adress

Tags: c#

I want scrape element value from url adress by c# but dont work program.
I tested many codes but I could not get the element value

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;

var web = new HtmlWeb();

var doc = web.Load("http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=5516102131364383");

var element = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[contains(@class,'ltr inline')]");

MessageBox.Show(element.InnerText);
```

[image]

Comment: If you use .net core then this method  is not available: https://html-agility-pack.net/from-browser

Comment: @ggeorge : What method is not available?  From what I see people are successfully using the HTML agility Pack with Core.  Some web methods are not working.  but in this case the OP is getting a response.

Comment: Thank you ggeorge. I already tested it but it didn't work properly

Comment: @jdweng, I mean about loading from browser, there is a note about it in the official documentation of hap. Also a common practice for such scenarios is to use some automation framework like selenium.

Comment: @far could you provide us a valid URL to check it, because i tried this one i see above but i could not access the web page

Comment: I can get the amount of element using Selenium, but I don't want to use Selenium

Comment: Unfortunately, the website is filtered and we must use VPN   http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=5516102131364383

Comment: The body of the webpage is text (HTML) and the text is the input to the HTML Agility Pack.  You should be able to just search for the class name.  If that is not working try by id : https://html-agility-pack.net/knowledge-base/37130244/htmlagilitypack---how-to-get-the-tag-by-id-